# Full Crawl and Continous crawl

Tags: 2013, search, enterprise-search

We have SharePoint 2013 environment and search is set as continuous crawl. We are planning to map crawled properties to managed properties and need to do a full crawl:

Do you need to switch the crawl from continues to full? or can we do a full crawl while continuous crawl is enabled by using powershell?

Answer (score 1):

You need to full crawl, as my experience, continuous crawl will not pick these changes.
You dont need to change the schduel the continuous crawl rather manually run the full crawl.

```
From Central admin > search services application > Content Source > click on drop next to the your Content Source and click on full crawl.
```

But if you want to use the powershell, then managed properties can be added without requiring Full Crawl.

http://olafd.wordpress.com/2013/08/20/add-a-crawled-property-in-sharepoint-2013/